# Yii:Property "CActiveDataProvider.select" is not defined

Tags: yii

I am using a slave db, and when i switch the db connection, this is what i get:

what does this mean?

```
CException

Property "CActiveDataProvider.select" is not defined.

public function actionIndex() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = 'user_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->id;
    VillageSlaveM::$server_id = Yii::app()->session['user_active_world'];
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('VillageSlaveM', $criteria);
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of line:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('VillageSlaveM', $criteria);
```

try

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('VillageSlaveM', array('criteria'=>$criteria));
```

I'm not sure, but [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#__construct-detail) describes CActiveDataProvider's construct.